# Prove $\left( \frac{ n }{ n-1 } \right)^{ n-1 } = \left( \frac{ n-1 }{ n } \right)^{ 1-n }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I have seen this equation:

$$\left( \frac{ n }{ n-1 } \right)^{ n-1 } = \left( \frac{ n-1 }{ n } \right)^{ 1-n }$$

As you can see the numerator switched with the denominator and I wonder how. I know power laws and yet I can not quite figure out what happened here.

Comment: $(\frac 1 x)^{y}=x^{-y}$.

Comment: This is $(a/b)^c=(b/a)^{-c}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{(n)^{n-1}}{(n-1)^{n-1}}=\frac{(n-1)^{-(n-1)}}{(n)^{-(n-1)}}=\frac{(n-1)^{1-n}}{(n)^{1-n}}=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{1-n}$

Comment: How did you go from the second to the third step?

Comment: From the properties mentioned in the comments above:  $x^{-y}=1/x^y$.

Comment: $$n^{ n-1 }=n^{ n }n^{ -1 }=n^{ n }\frac{ 1 }{ n }=\frac{ n^{ n } }{ n }$$ is this so far correct? What would the next step be? (I only looked at the numerator for simplification purposes)

Comment: Yes, that appears consistent. I don't know what you mean by next step though. Next step to accomplish what?

Comment: If I continue calculating in the very end I get: $$n^{ n+1 }-n^{ n }$$ and I do not know how to proceed ( I only used the numerator to simplify, the denominator would be accordingly.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108819/discussion-between-graham-and-math-noob).

Comment: I have now tried out a few things and I do understand now how what you have described works. Thank you very much !